# State is updating but the app isn't updated/

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my rock paper scissors app the PcRandomChoice sometimes doesn't update in the function and update to a new choice. The same thing also sometimes happens to my User choice. What am I doing wrong? I can update with my codesandbox link. Is this a state management problem? When you console.log the choices it is showing the random user choice updating but not updating the other variable.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactInfo from "./ResultInfo";
import { ScoreAlert } from "./Alert";
import { Button, Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { weapons } from "./data";

const WeaponButton = props => {
  const { name, id, attackAction } = props;
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => attackAction(id)}
      className="myButton"
      variant="outline-primary"
      size="md"
    >
      {name}
    </Button>
  );
};

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 10,
      ran: "",
      id: "",
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1),
      draw: {
        score: 0
      },
      user: {
        score: 0,
        choice: ""
      },
      pc: {
        score: 0,
        choice: ""
      },
      roundLimit: 10,
      roundWinner: ""
    };

    this.setWinner = this.setWinner.bind(this);
    this.setWeapon = this.setWeapon.bind(this);
    this.battle = this.battle.bind(this);
    this.attack = this.attack.bind(this);
  }

  setWeapon = (pcId, userId) => {

    const [ pcWeaponName, userWeaponName] = [pcId, userId].map(weaponId => weapons.find(w => w.weaponId === weaponId).name);

    console.log(this.state.pc.choice, pcWeaponName)

    this.setState({
      user: { score: this.state.user.score, choice: userWeaponName },
      pc: { score: this.state.pc.score, choice: pcWeaponName }
    });
  };

  setWinner = (winner = "draw") => {
    const { score, choice } = this.state[winner];

    const newScore = score + 1;

    this.setState({
      roundWinner: winner,
      [winner]: { score: newScore, choice }
    });
  };

  battle = userWeaponId => {
    //Get PC Choice
    const generatePcWeapon = () =>
      [...weapons][Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];

    const pcWeapon = generatePcWeapon();
    const { weaponId: pcWeaponId, weaknesses = [] } = pcWeapon;
    // Get User Choice

    // Compare IDs
    if (pcWeaponId === userWeaponId) {
      // Update roundWinner to Draw
      this.setWinner();
      // Return
      return;
    }

    // Search for user choice in PC Weaknesses

    this.setWeapon(pcWeaponId, userWeaponId);

    const winner = weaknesses.includes(userWeaponId) ? "user" : "pc";

    this.setWinner(winner);
  };

  attack = id => {
    this.battle(id); // your alert function
  };

  render(props) {
    const { user, pc, roundWinner } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <Container fluid>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <h5>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h5>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <h6> Select Your Weapon </h6>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            {weapons.map(({ name, weaponId }) => {
              return (
                <Row key={weaponId}>
                  <Col>
                    <WeaponButton
                      attackAction={this.attack}
                      id={weaponId}
                      name={name}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              );
            })}{" "}
          </Container>
        </div>

        <ReactInfo
          id={user.choice}
          ran={pc.choice}
          roundWinner={roundWinner}
          userPoint={user.score}
          pcPoint={pc.score}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Shallow comparison is probably the issue

Your state is not shallow, i.e. you have objects inside objects. When state changes are detected a shallow comparison is done. To stop this from happening you should make a copy of the state before setting it.
A very easy way to do that is to JSON.Stringify and JSON.parse. This is CPU intensive, but shouldn't be an issue in this code, it's not very complex.

#### Do this first to check if shallow comparison is the actual issue

```
setWinner = (winner = "draw") => {
    const { score, choice } = this.state[winner];

    const newScore = score + 1;

    const stateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
      roundWinner: winner,
      [winner]: { score: newScore, choice }
    }))

    this.setState(stateCopy);
  };
```

```
  setWeapon = (pcId, userId) => {

    const [ pcWeaponName, userWeaponName] = [pcId, userId].map(weaponId => weapons.find(w => w.weaponId === weaponId).name);

    console.log(this.state.pc.choice, pcWeaponName)
    const stateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
      user: { score: this.state.user.score, choice: userWeaponName },
      pc: { score: this.state.pc.score, choice: pcWeaponName }
    }))
    this.setState(stateCopy);
  };
```

#### If shallow comparison is the issue lets improve it

A better way would be to spread your object out so that its always new, you probably want to spread out the inner objects as well, since its also do shallow copy when the spread is used. But you'll need to go through that in your own code to test it.

```
setWinner = (winner = "draw") => {
    const { score, choice } = this.state[winner];

    const newScore = score + 1;

    const stateCopy = {
      roundWinner: winner,
      [winner]: { score: newScore, choice }
    }

    this.setState({...stateCopy});
  };
```

```
  setWeapon = (pcId, userId) => {

    const [ pcWeaponName, userWeaponName] = [pcId, userId].map(weaponId => weapons.find(w => w.weaponId === weaponId).name);

    console.log(this.state.pc.choice, pcWeaponName)
    const stateCopy = {
      user: { score: this.state.user.score, choice: userWeaponName },
      pc: { score: this.state.pc.score, choice: pcWeaponName }
    }
    this.setState({...stateCopy});
  };
```

Comment: No this didn't solve it unfortunately but thank you